# How to plot fitted value and forecasted value with true observation

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, time-series, forecasting

I have got training data and testing data, and I fitted model using `tbats` in the `forecast` package.

```
demand.train<-demand[1:94920,]
demand.train.ts<-msts(demand.train$Demand,seasonal.period=c(48,7*48,91.25*48,365*48),start=2011)
demand.train.model<-tbats(demand.train.ts)
fc1.week<-forecast(demand.train.model,h=48*7)
plot(fc1.week)
```

I am wondering:

1. How to plot fitted value and true observations in the same plot?
2. How to plot forecasted value and its confidence interval? (`plot` can do that, but my time series is too large, the forecasted value is at the very end of the plot, thus hard to observe. I want the one with only forecasted value and CI, without including all previous time series)
3. How to add test data to the second plot.

Comment: Use `matplot` function

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways that you might want to consider:

First let's grab some freely available data

```
library(ggplot2)
my_data <- mtcars
```

Show prediction within plotting function, as a line with confidence interval

```
plot_internal <- ggplot(my_data)+
  aes(x = wt, y = mpg)+
  # raw data
  geom_point()+
  # LM 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
plot_internal
```

[image]

I suspect that you actually want to know how to show predictions based on an explicit model. Here's how to do it:

```
my_model <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data=my_data)

# add the fitted values right into the data frame
my_data$fitted <- fitted(my_model)
```

Now plot the real and fitted values as separate layers.

```
plot_external <- ggplot(my_data)+
  aes(x = wt)+
  # raw data
  geom_point(aes(y = mpg))+
  # fitted values
  geom_point(aes(y=fitted), color = "purple")
plot_external
```

[image]

Special sauce: draw arrows connecting real and fitted values

```
plot_with_residual_arrows <- ggplot(my_data)+
  aes(x = wt)+
  # raw data
  geom_point(aes(y = mpg))+
  # fitted values
  geom_point(aes(y=fitted), color = "purple")+
  # plot arrows from predicted to real values
  geom_segment(aes(xend = wt, y = fitted, yend = mpg),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.4, "line")), 
               color="red")
plot_with_residual_arrows
```

[image]

A side note: in these cases, sometimes a legend for designating real and fitted values is nice. Various other questions on SO can help you with that - it's a simple matter of melting the data or setting explicit legends.

Comment: Thanks. I am very new to ggplot, so don't quiet understand the code. Should x and y be in the same dataset? In my case, both x and y are multiple seasonal time series object, does that matter? It shows error: `Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type msts/ts. Defaulting to continuous.`

Comment: if you want to use ggplot2, then yes, they both needs to be columns in the same data.frame. I don't know what msts/ts objects are. I'm sure someone could provide some example code to plot using base R, but ggplot2 offers some very nice features that you might want to consider.